# ServiceError with basic Direct Line interaction

Tags: botframework, direct-line-botframework

I've got a basic bot that I am trying to interact with via Direct Line. Following [this example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-direct-line-3-0-authentication), these are what my requests look like:

**Start Conversation**

[image]

**Send Activity**

[image]

The error it responds with is difficult to investigate with such minimal information. The bot itself is working perfectly on other channels.

Has anyone seen this before?

Comment: When sending the activity, try putting the token from Start Conversation response in Authorization header

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apologies for answering my own question. It turns out, the Send Activity request was sent as `application/text` instead of `application/json`.

I wish the error was more clear on why it was rejecting it but that fixed my issue.